# Can't find bjam in boost homebrew installation

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, homebrew

I installed Boost with homebrew(`brew install boost`) on my Mac running Lion with the purpose of extending python with an existing C++ program I have. Now I can't follow the [starting guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/hello.html) because 1 - I don't have 'bjam' installed in my system and 2-I don't see the examples folder anywhere. My question is: how I am supposed to do the the c++-python linking with this homebrew installation without 'bjam'? is there some alternative method I should use or something I am missing here?

Comment: Are your formulas up-to-date? [Boost-jam is now part of boost-build](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/279fac113007acc9589f4aa49a4ded3f6c059c9f)

Comment: so I should do 'brew install boost-build'? I made 'brew install boost'

Comment: Ok that was the problem, I installed boost-build and its all ok, would you make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The right formula to install boost for linking c++ with python programs is:
`brew install boost-build`
as pointed out by senderle in the comments to my question. This installs `bjam` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you go into $(BoostDir)\tools\build\v2\engine and run build.bat which automatically builds bjam (into the bin.ntx86 directory on windows). There is a build.sh file there too, but I've never used a Mac so I don't know if that will work for you. Otherwise, just do a Google search for a precompiled bjam executable for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a case of downloading Boost then running "Bootstrap" followed by "Bjam".

Bootstrap should build you a Bjam executable in the Boost folder.